# Meaning of ".active?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing my first Rails app and I'm confused by a method call that I've seen in some of the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).  In the snippet below, what does the call to `project.active?` do?

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <% @person.projects.each do |project| %>
    <% if project.active? %>
      <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, project do |project_fields| %>
        Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I've tried looking for the source code of `.active?`, but I can't find it... I searched through [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), which I assume is the superclass of `project`, but it's not there.  I don't know where else to look.

Does anyone know what the `.active?` method does, and where I can find documentation on it?

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, in this case, your model `Project` has a boolean field on it named `active`. `active?` is a shortcut for booleans that ActiveRecord provides: it returns true or false based on the value of that boolean.

As a side note, the naked field name operates the same way -- so `project.active`, just like `project.active?`, will return `true` or `false`. But most Ruby methods that return `true` or `false` end with a question mark, so boolean fields get an alias of their name plus a question mark for convenience.